# What kind of custom entitlements do exist?

Tags: ios, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

Apple offers a nice [List of Entitlements](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2415/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016427-CH1-ENTITLEMENTSLIST)
 and [Entitlement Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AboutEntitlements.html) that anyone can use.

But there also exist some "custom entitlements" that you can only use if your app identifier was whitelisted for their usage.

3 examples:

- `com.apple.developer.passkit.pass-presentation-suppression` = Suppressing the Display of Apple Pay Passes
- `com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning` = Enabling In-App Provisioning of Payment Cards
- `com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotHelper` = Register an app as a Hotspot Helper

The first two are actually listed via the Key Reference on [Apple Pay and PassKit Entitlement Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/ApplePayandPassKitEntitlements/ApplePayandPassKitEntitlements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH7-SW5), but the third is only listed on [some code documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspothelper) (see yellow box).

What kind of custom entitlements do exist?

Comment: Probably impossible to know. Some apps have special privileges that you and I can't get.

Comment: I hope it's only "not trivial" - but there has to be a list (or multiple lists that can be combined) somewhere or with someone. I hope one of them is reading Stack Overflow :)

Comment: `com.apple.developer.carplay-maps` is another one for enabling Appple CarPlay.